# Unsorted table data is rendered along with sorted data in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js

I'm using React to sort table using underscore.js, but the sorted data is added to the bottom of the table along with the original data. I need to just render the sorted table in my component. What is the correct way to achieve this?

```
 class Players extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = { players:[]};
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     fetch('http://localhost:5000/players')
     .then((data) => data.json())
     .then((data) => this.setState( { players: data } ));
   }

   sortByCode = () => {
     this.setState( { "players": _.sortBy(this.state.players,'TEAMCODE')});
   }
 render() {
   return (
    <table border={1}>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th onClick={this.sortByCode}>Code</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        {this.state.players.map( (item) => {
          return 
            <tr key={item.TEAMCODE}>
              <td><img height={20} width ={20} 
       alt="pics" src={'/logos/' + item.TEAMCODE + '_logo.svg'}></img> 
       </td>
              <td>{item.TEAMCODE}</td>
              <td>{item.NAME}</td></tr>;
        })}
        </tbody>
    </table>
 )};
```

Comment: The issue is `key={item.TEAMCODE}` which screws up React internally. React actually warns you about this in the console. Use the index instead. https://codesandbox.io/s/73ypq45426

Comment: Ah excellent! I seen the error but assumed it was something else I was missing.Thank you

Comment: I've again updated my sandbox, adding a unique `ID` to each `player` which is used as key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not recommended to use the index as a key (see [ReactJS documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html))

I would advise to find the unique key of your dataset that seems to be the combination of TEAMCODE and NAME so you should replace your code with :

```
<tr key={item.TEAMCODE+item.NAME}>
```

Comment: Right, I've updated my sandbox using exactly this :)